# C++/CLI Windows Form change gif then to image

Tags: c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

The code is simple. After a button press, change current image to the gif, then to the image after the gif.

The goal is have the gif play, then switch to the jpg. From the get go, this does not work. I've tried different timing techniques such as using Sleep(), for loops, and a mix of the two. This doesn't this doesn't give the gif time to play at all. The image remains as the primary, delays for however long and jumps to the jpg.

After a button press how can I change images, even gifs, in a specified order with a specified delay time between each?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {
                pictureBox1->Load("gif");
                pictureBox1->Load("jpg");
             }
```

Comment: Your code is C++/CLI not C++. Please tag your posts appropriately.

Comment: Will do. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from Michail who posted here, I was able to find a solution to the problem. The form had a predetermined jpg in pictureBox1. This code allows a gif to play for a determined amount of time in pictureBox1. Once that time has been met, it changes the image in pictureBox1 to a different jpg than before. This method could also be used as a timed loading screen if one finds a way to apply it as such. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
    #pragma endregion

        public:
            static int second = 0;

        private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            if(second != 42)
            {
                second++;
            }
            if(second >= 42)
            {
                pictureBox1->Load(".jpg");
                timer1->Enabled=false;
            }
        }

        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            pictureBox1->Load(".gif");
            timer1->Enabled=true;
        }
```

Comment: you also can set timer1->Interval  to 42000 and dont count seconds. do not forget to stop timer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
            pictureBox1->Load("gif");
            Timer->Enabled=true;
         }

private: System::Void Timer_tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
           pictureBox1->Load("jpg");
         }
```